# signature seems to be signed in future error while verify signature in foxit

Tags: itext, digital-signature, foxit, foxit-reader

I am getting below error while click on signature & validate signature.

**Signature Validation Status.**

- Signature is INVALID.
- Signature seems to be signed in future.
- Certified by the current user.

I am signing in my local machine and open signed pdf in local machine.

**Foxit version** :  7.3.4.311

Same file open in adobe reader and i am able to validate signature in adobe.I am using c# and Itextsharp for pdf signing.

Comment: I added the Foxit and Foxit-Reader tags. Since Adobe Reader doesn't complain, I am assuming that this isn't an iText problem.

Comment: That sounds like one of the validators (Foxit or Adobe) interprets dates in the wrong timezone please share a sample PDF, tell us when you have signed it (local time + time zone), and show your pivotal signing code.